# Whats wrong with the following FORTRAN 77 code?

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I am a total FORTRAN 77 newbie, and I don't understand why the first code shows an error while the second one compiles when I expect them to do the same.

First code (which doesn't compile and gives a error citing an unexpected data declaration statement at z):

```
program FOO

integer x, y

x = 1
y = 2

integer z 

z = 3

end
```

This code which looks 100% similar in functionality to the first one compiles without errors

```
program FOO

integer x, y, z

x = 1
y = 2
z = 3

end
```

I also tried disabling implicit variable declarations in the first code with no effects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fortran is one of those quaint "define everything at the top" languages. In other words, this would be fine:

```
program FOO
    integer x, y
    integer z 
    x = 1
    y = 2
    z = 3
end
```

since all type specifications are before any executable code. If you're *going* to define a variable, you should define it first. See [here](http://www.idris.fr/data/cours/lang/fortran/f90/F77.html#p2.4.1) for example:

> Such non-executable statements must be placed at the beginning of a program, before the first executable statement.

Comment: yeah, even I guessed that. But if that's the case, then its vital information and should be in the FORTRAN books. But I couldn't find a single reference to this.

Comment: This is correct. Executable statements must be after all variable declarations.

Comment: It _does_ seem a rather important aspect, doesn't it? Added a link to a tutorial which suggests this is the case but I guess the ANSI standards docs would be the best. I have the ISO C ones since I've done a bit of work on compilers for that, but I can't really justify the cost of the Fortran ones since no-one will pay me for such a beast :-)

Comment: @phycker: If your fortran books were half decent, they would contain this info; if they don't, I would ditch them and find others. @paxdiablo: Although the official standard documents aren't free, the final draft (which is the one that gets voted on by the committee) is freely available. The gfortran wiki has a page with links to them: http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranStandards.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know real solution but maybe `fortran77` doesn't support any code between variables.

for example;

```
integer x, y, z

x = 1
y = 2
z = 3
```

works but

```
integer x, y

x = 1
y = 2

integer z 

z = 3
```

doesn't work. Because between two integer definening (`integer x, y` and `integer z` ), there are variables assigning.

Answer (score 1):

@paxdiablo: you think right!

and the errormessage:

"... unexpected data declaration statement at ..."

all DELCARATION must be made BEFORE the first STATEMENT occurs. fortran77 is really "old", I´m not shure if this is changed in F95

Comment: I know it's not changed in Fortran90 and am fairly certain it is not changed if Fortran95. It is best practice to declare variables at the top of a function/subroutine/program, anyway.

Comment: The same rule is still in effect as of the latest version of the standard, Fortran 2008.

Answer (score 1):

For your information: Disabling implicit variable declarations simply removes Fortan's ability to make assumptions about what type your variables are.

Implicit variable declaration makes the following assumptions: Any variable beginning with (capital or lowercase): I, J, K, L, M, or N is to be INTEGER. Any variable beginning with any other letter (capital or lowercase) is to be REAL. This applies only to variables which do not have an explicit type declaration.

You could write:

```
program FOO
ijk
ifjkask    
end
```

and ijk and ifjkask would be INTEGER values.